# hibernate joined subclass table is not creating when same table name exists in different db

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="A" table="A">
        <!- properties ->
        <joined-subclass name="B" table="B">
            <!- properties ->
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Classes

```
public class A{
    //Instance variables
    public A(){
    
    }

    // getters and setters for instance variables
}


public class B extends A{
    // Instance variables of B
    public B(){
    
    }
    // Setters and getters for class B
}
```

I am using hibernate 5.0.7 version. I have hibernate mapping like mentioned above. B is extending A class(Both are not abstract). When hibernate is getting initialized table 'A' is not creating, an exception being thrown. There is a same table name 'A' in other database(MySQL). For simple tables adding "schema" to hibernate cfg (class tag) solved the issue. But for inherited super class and sub class this is not working. Is there any configuration I am missing?

### Exception

org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:112)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:346)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)

Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table db.A not found
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getTableId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5107)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:433)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
... 10 more

Comment: Can you please post your class files and mappings correctly here?

Comment: @venkat, Edited question and formatted code for properly displaying in stack overflow.